# sobel operator or canny operator,which one gives better result

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, edge-detection

I m doing project on face detection in C#.net, in some cases i got better result from sobel & in some other from canny.but in real which one is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canny is built on top of Sobel operator. Basically, it is an improvement of Sobel operator.

So I would say Canny.

Comment: To say that Canny is "built on top" of the Sobel operator sounds weird. I would rather say you can apply Sobel to find the intensity gradient in the image. This is just one of many steps in the Canny algorithm.

Comment: I think that "being built on top of X" and "using X as a first step" are synonymous... Moreover Sobel was invented before Canny.

Comment: (I cannot edit my first comment) @HåvardGeithus, I think that "being built on top of X" and "using X as a first step" are synonymous... Canny edge detector replaces a standard thresholding by a smart hysteresis thresholding, "on top of" the Sobel operator.